Neo4j ConsistencyCheckService return a lot of inconsistency errors
I have a database that is running for 6 months now, i just bumped into the follwoing error:
2024-06-12 09:10:11.864+0000 ERROR Client triggered an unexpected error [Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.TransactionCommitFailed]: Unable to complete transaction., reference 25ad85a0-5da8-43f6-bdd9-0f342e9959ee.
I run inconsistency check and this is the result.
2024-06-13 12:12:55.046+0000 WARN  [o.n.c.ConsistencyCheckService] Inconsistencies found: ConsistencySummaryStatistics {
        Number of errors: 10345
        Number of warnings: 25
        Number of inconsistent PROPERTY records: 16
        Number of inconsistent NODE records: 7791
        Number of inconsistent RELATIONSHIP records: 2538
}

this didn't help: How to solve ERROR Index inconsistency: Index has a leaked page that will never be reclaimed, pageId=X? Neo4j
I can read from the database but I can't write.
Thanks

What version of Neo4j are you running? Looks like you can rebuild the node/relationship stores, which should resync the results you are seeing in the consistency checker. However, the steps below are only recommended for version 4.4 and below.
Description: The below errors are indicative of the count metadata at either the node or relationship corresponding to the actual number of nodes or relationships
Recovery: Rebuild the node/relationship count stores. To do this stop the database using bin/neo4j stop and then remove the files named 'neostore.counts.db.\*' from your graph.db/ directory. Restarting Neo4j, via bin/neo4j start, will rebuild these files.

Example Error Messages:

2016-02-03 09:09:23.181+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: The node count does not correspond with the expected count.
    CountsEntry[NodeKey[(:label=1)]: 1447977]
    Inconsistent with: 2775235

2016-02-03 09:09:23.209+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: The relationship count does not correspond with the expected count.
CountsEntry[RelationshipKey[()-->()]: 12945949]
Inconsistent with: 24654501

